# Filter lines of a giant file based on the values from another file in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to read and filter lines from a giant file (1.5 TB). 
 The giant file's content looks like this

```
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q31> <schema#label> "Beligium"@en .
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q31> <schema#label> "Bilkiya"@ay .
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q31> <schema#label> "Belgique"@fr .
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q31> <schema#label> "Beriyum"@na .
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q54> <schema#label> "Japan"@en .
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q112> <schema#label> "asasa"@en .
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q112> <schema#label> "ssdd"@fr .
<https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_discographique> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://schema.org/Article> .
<https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_discographique> <http://schema.org/about> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18127> .
```

We want to extract only the lines that match the following pattern

```
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/(ID_LIST)> < schema#label> "(.+)"@(en|fr) .
```

for example for ID_LIST = [Q31,Q54], we would extract

```
    <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q31> <schema#label> "Beligium"@en .
    <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q31> <schema#label> "Belgique"@fr .
    <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q54> <schema#label> "Japan"@en .
```

Using this command

```
rg =  re.compile('<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/(Q31|Q54)> <schema#label> "(.+)"@(en|fr) .')   
rdd = sc.textFile(file_name).filter(lambda x:  rg.match(x))
```

My question is how about if ID_LIST, is coming from another file that includes 2 million ids? Should we pipe these two millions in our regex?  Is this efficient?

Of course the easy solution is to extract all lines that match the general pattern

```
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/(.+)> < schema#label> "(.+)"@(en|fr)
```

and then by converting the ID_LIST to another rdd or data frame, use a join operation to extract only lines that match the ID_LIST

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [join](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.join).

(Pseudo-code, may not work)

```
# Define extract_id to return the ID of a chunk of XML

idwanted_rdd = sc.textfile(id_file_name).keyBy(lambda _: _)
data_rdd = sc.textFile(data_file_name).keyBy(extract_id)
result = idwanted_rdd.join(data_rdd).map(lambda (k, v): (k, v[1]))
```

Result will contain pairs of `(id, data)`